# How do I pass an array to a method in java?

Tags: java, arrays, methods

Here is the program that I am trying to run:

```
/**
 * Write a description of class mainGame here.
 * 
 * @author Anthony Parsch
 * @version 0.1.1
 */

//Import what I need to.
import java.io.*;
public class mainGame
{

    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class mainGame
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // initialise instance variables
        int xCoord = 10; //The map's max x coordinate +1
        int yCoord = 10; //The map's max y coordinate +1

        int playerX = 0; //The player's current x coordinate
        int playerY = 0; //The player's current y coordinate

        //Declare the arrays
        String[][] map; //[x][y]The map
        String[][] direc; //[x][y]Which directions that you can go
        String[][] items; //[x][y]Where items are at
        String[] inv; // Holds your inventory.
        int[][] helpInt; //[x][y] All the other stuff in the 

        //Initalize the arrays

        //---The player arrays
        inv = new String[10]; //The player's inventory
        inv[0] = "0";
        inv = addItem(inv, "Blarg");//GET RID OF THIS LATER

        //---The map arrays
        map = new String[xCoord][yCoord]; //Descriptions
        direc = new String[xCoord][yCoord]; //north y++,west x--,south y--,east x++
        items = new String[xCoord][yCoord]; //The items within the world



        //Declare the values of map
        map[0][0] = "You wake up with the feel of cold metal on your back. The only other thing in this room is the door.";
        map[0][1] = "You are now in a hallway with a door behind you and one either side. Forward is a continuation of the hallway.com";


        //Declare the values of direc
        direc[0][0] = "north";
        direc[0][1] = "north, south, east, west";

        print(inv[0]);  //Check that the functions work
        print(findDirec(direc, 0, 0));
    }

    /**
     * Finds and displays the avaliable exits for a coordinate.
     * 
     * @param  map[][]   The map array from which this method pulls the directions from.
     * @param  x         The x value of the map
     * @param  y         The y value of the map
     * @return           The string value of which way you can go
     */
    static String findDirec(String[][] map, int x, int y){
        //Pulls the directions
        String match = map[x][y];

        //Checks Directions
        boolean nor = match.matches("(.*)north(.*)");
        boolean sou = match.matches("(.*)south(.*)");
        boolean wes = match.matches("(.*)west(.*)");
        boolean eas = match.matches("(.*)east(.*)");

        //Displays directions
        String placeHolder = "You can go ";

        if (nor == true){
            placeHolder = placeHolder + "north, ";
        } else if(sou == true) {
            placeHolder = placeHolder + "south, ";
        } else if(wes == true) {
            placeHolder = placeHolder + "west, ";
        } else if(eas == true) {
            placeHolder = placeHolder + "east";
        }

        //---Checks if east is in the string, if not it removes the space and comma
        if (eas == false){
            StringBuffer soo = new StringBuffer(placeHolder);

            soo.delete((placeHolder.length()-3), (placeHolder.length()-1));
            placeHolder = soo.toString();
        }

        //Adds the ending period
        placeHolder = placeHolder + ".";

        //Returns the string
        return placeHolder;
    }

    //Adds an item to an inventory
    static String[] addItem(String inv[], String item){
        int i; //Counter for the for loop, and where to add the item at.
        boolean stop = false;

        for(i=0; stop = true; i++)
        {
            if(inv[i].equals("0"))
            {
                stop = true;
            }
        }
        inv[i] = item;
        return inv;
    }
    static void print(String entry){
        System.out.print(entry);
    }
}
```

And when I try and run it through the Command Prompt, I get this error:
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerExcpetion
        at mainGame.addItem(mainGame.java:113)
        at mainGame.main(mainGame.java:38)

Comment: Which line is 113? Have you looked at that line and tried to work out which pointer might be null, and why?

Comment: some `inv[i]` is `null` and you can't do `inv[i].equals("0")` if `inv[i]` is `null`

Comment: A thought: you might want to consider using an `ArrayList<String>` to represent inventory.  Then you don't need to worry about nulls, finding the end of the list, etc; you can just say `inv.add(item)`.  For a short list, even removing items is not a huge deal.

Comment: (BTW, `main` is not a constructor.  And your variables declared within it, are by definition not instance variables -- they're just locals.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    inv = new String[10]; //The player's inventory
    inv[0] = "0";
    inv = addItem(inv, "Blarg");//GET RID OF THIS LATER
```

So you only initialize one index of your array but here:

```
   for(i=0; stop = true; i++)
    {
        if(inv[i].equals("0"))
        {
            stop = true;
        }
    }
```

.. <s>you loop through all of them.</s> just kidding, didn't read the full problem. You should still read the rest of my answer, but the reason why you get the NPE is because your loop condition is broken. (by the way your for loop condition is broken, it should test for equivalence using the `==` operator, not the assignment `=` operator.)

So what you actually are doing with that code is this :

```
inv = new String[10];
```

At this point you have a new String array of capacity 10, with no values inside, something like this:

`[null][null][null][null][null][null][null][null][null][null]`

```
    inv[0] = "0";
```

Now you set [0] to "0", so:

`["0"][null][null][null][null][null][null][null][null][null]`

Then your loop attempts to access all of those null references, that'll probably be why you have a null reference exception.

To fix it, simply every index position in your array to anything that is not-null:

```
Arrays.fill(inv, "");
```

I use [Arrays.fill() because it's shorter.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#fill%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D,%20java.lang.Object%29)

Answer (score 2):

When I paste this in to a text editor, line 113 is simply a closing brace `}`.

However, one line before that is a logic flaw which I presume is really line 113 for you.

```
    for(i=0; stop = true; i++)
    {
        if(inv[i].equals("0"))
        {
            stop = true;
        }
    }
```

Each iteration of the loop assigns `true` to `stop` and then tests if `true` equals `true`, which it does.  Your condition to exit the loop is when `true` equals `false`, which is never the case, therefore your loop goes forever until an error occurs.  Also, don't you want to iterate while `stop` is `false`?  I think you have it backwards.

The next problem is your if statement, which is probably where your `NullPointerException` is coming from:

```
        if(inv[i].equals("0"))
        {
            stop = true;
        }
```

You assume that `inv[i]` refers to an object.  You need a null check.

Three recommendations:

1. Never use `=` for a comparison.  Use `==`.  Since this is a boolean, you can even simplify this to `stop`.
2. Check the length in your for loop.
3. Compare "0" to inv[i] instead of the other way around to avoid null pointer dereferencing.

Try this:

```
boolean stop = false;
for (int i = 0; i < inv.length && !stop; i++)
{
    if("0".equals(inv[i])
    {
        stop = true;
    }
}
```

Another option, and this is a matter of form, is to remove the looping variable and just break out of the loop explicitly.

```
for (int i = 0; i < inv.length; i++)
{
    if("0".equals(inv[i])
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Oi.  I hadn't even noticed the `=` vs `==`.  Good catch :)

Answer (score 0):

In your for loop condition, which one do you prefer?

stop = true or stop == true

Comment: `stop = true` will cause an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`, not an NPE.

Comment: @Brandon No it won't.  Keep going past the "0", and you'll get a null String next time round, which you call `.equals` on.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(i=0; i<inv.length && !stop; i++)
{
    if(inv[i]!=null && inv[i].equals("0"))
    {
        stop = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Though if you're going to allow `null` to exist in the array at all, it makes more sense to use that (rather than `"0"`) to indicate a free slot...